# Side news not showing aside in Chrome or FF or any other browser, CSS

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to use the flexible box model to write my CSS. The side news doesn't seem to show on the side. The navigation menu doesn't show horizontally. No matter which browser i use. Anyone know what is wrong with my CSS?

Css code is here:

```
*{
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
h1{
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
}
h2 {
    font: bold 14px Tahoma;
}
header, section, footer, aside, nav, article, hgroup {
        display: block;
}
body{
    width:100%;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
}
#big_wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin:20px 0px;
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:vertical;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
}
#top_header{
    background:yellow;
    border:3px solid black;
    padding:20px;
}
#top_menu{
    border:red;
    background:blue;
    color:white;
}
top_menu li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style:none;
    padding:5px;
    font:bold 20px Tahoma;
}
#new_div {
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;
}
#main_section{
    border: 1px solid blue;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
}
#side_news {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 220px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 30px; 
    background: #66CCCC;
}
#the_footer{
    text-align:center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 2px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Ok I noticed one # missing in front of top_menu li. Adding it solved the navigation menu problem. But the side news issue I still can't figure out.

Comment: Please add the HTML. You should post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: This comment pointed me in the right direction. One ID name in the HTML was not matching with the ID in the CSS. Simple mistake with big consequences. Thanks Michael.